# How to prove Gamma is the same for a European call and European put with the same inputs?

Tags: greeks, put-call-parity, gamma

I saw from a text "**From put-call parity, call and put with the same inputs have the same gamma**", but I don't see how put-call parity is related to Gamma. Can someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Put-call parity says that a call and put (worth $C$ and $P$ respectively) with the same strike $K$ have the following relationship with the spot rate $S$, risk-free rate $r$, and time to maturity $T$ --

$$C - P = S - e^{-rT} K$$

Taking the first derivative with respect to $S$,

$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial S} = 1
$$

which relates the delta of the call and put. Taking the second derivative,

$$
\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} - \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S^2} = 0
$$

which implies that the call and put have the same gamma.

Comment: LOL it's so easy. Thanks.